# rails how to save a model with has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I am having models like

```
// Contains the details of Parties (Users)
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :party_races
 has_many :races, :through=>:party_races
end

// Contains the party_id and race_id  mappings
class PartyRace < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :party
 belongs_to :race
end

// Contains list of races like Asian,American,etc..
class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :party_races
 has_many :parties, :through => :party_races
end
```

Now, lets say I'm creating an instance of Party
`party_instance = Party.new`

**How am I supposed to add multiple Races** to `party_instance` and save to database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nested attributes to make one form that allows children. There are many examples on this site. Read up on the following first:

- [Accepts nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
- [Fields for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)
- [A railscast about your use case](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments)

Answer (score 0):

You also can create new PartyRace for each Races that you can add:

```
def addRace( party_instance, new_race )
  party_race = PartyRace.new( party: party_instance, race: new_race )
  party_race.save
end
```